# Dwolla Two Phase Commit

Tags: transactions, xa, dwolla

For those that develop applications using Dwolla to conduct business transactions, how do you perform two phase commits? Dwolla appears to have a wonderful REST API, but given that REST is conceptually stateless how have others updated their databases and sent money within a transaction? To illustrate, we have the concept of a wallet which will contain money that our users have accumulated, but how can I update the user's wallet in our DB and send the money via Dwolla all within one transaction?

Thanks in advance, I'm hoping since I'm relatively new to Dwolla that there's a piece of their API that I just haven't yet discovered.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a perfect use case for Dwolla's Webhook notifications:

https://developers.dwolla.com/dev/pages/webhooks